# Adding a Standard Deviation Measure,Removing by range

Tags: ssas, mdx, standard-deviation

In a Easy Cube layout i have a Product and Time dimension

my transaction cube has the unitary price of the product and the total value(quantity x unitary price)

sometimes when i got a product promotion(like :buy 2 get 3) we have the unitary price equal $0,01 for 1 record.

i want to remove from my average, maximum and minimun [measures] results all these records( $ 0,01)

i thinking about a standard deviation implementation, but this only work with my already set measures

i tried to add unitary price with a no aggregation measure (which would suit me) but i'm using standard edition

(and 'no aggregattion' its not available as measure type)

thanks for your time, sorry for my english

Arthur

Sao Paulo - Brazil

Answer (score 0):

The better approach (the MDX way) would be to add an attribute, say "On promotion" with members "Promo" and "regular".
Then just by either not using the attribute (and hence using the All member, which aggregates "Promo" and "regular", you get all measures including the promoted products, or by using just the member "regular" in a filter or in the rows or columns, all measures would include only the regular products.

There are approaches for implementing this  using your current cube model (probably using `Filter`), but they are complex to implement and slow.